# Synchronous server calls from actionscript

Tags: actionscript

how do you make a synchronous server call (POST) via actionscript? I'm trying to execute a call on the browsers unload event - but I think it needs to be synchronous in order to get called.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't make synchronous calls to server as in Javascript.

What I understand is that you want your swf to do a call to the server before closing the browser window - probably to log time used in a session

What you can do is the following:

1. IN FLASH: Add a callback function (A) in Flash using Actionscript ExternalInterface that does the following:

   A) Does the call to server using URLLoader and specifying the method as POST.

   B) calls window.close via ExternalInterface when the urlloader Event.COMPLETE handler fires
2. IN JSCRIPT: catch the onbeforeunload event of the browser and prevent it and call the call back function you defined in step 1 on flash to do the server call and then closes the window when it finishes the job.

Hope this helps!